# Trivial Tate modules

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-varieties, group-cohomology, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group, and $p$ a prime.

I'll call $$T_p(A) := \text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Z}}(\mathbf{Q}_{p}/\mathbf{Z}_{p}, A).$$

If $A$ is finite, then $T_p(A)$ is trivial, but the converse is not true.

What are the abelian groups $A$ for which $T_p(A) = 0$?

My guess is that they are those such that the subgroup of $p$-divisible elements is $p$-torsion free. I'll try it, but if anyone knows a general answer off the top of one's head, I'd be glad to have it.

More generally, let $K$ be a complex of abelian groups, and define:

$$T_p(K) := R\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Z}}(\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p[0], K).$$

When does $T_p(K)$ have trivial cohomology?

My guess is that the cohomology of $K$ must not contain $p$-torsion in its subgroup of $p$-divisible elements.

Thanks.

Comment: By 'divisible subgroup', do you mean the maximal divisible subgroup, or the subgroup of divisible elements (the latter need not be a divisible group).

Comment: Also, do you want $T_p(A) = 0$ for one prime $p$, or for all primes $p$?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I slightly changed the question.

Comment: For the second question: note that you have $T_p(K) =~ \widehat{K}[-1]$, where $\widehat{K}$ denotes the derived $p$-adic completion of $K$. It is well-known (and easy from derived Nakayama) that $\widehat{K} =~ 0$ if and only if $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}^L \mathbb{Z}/p \simeq 0$. Using the standard resolution, it follows that $T_p(K)$ has $0$ cohomology if and only each each $H^i(K)$ is uniquely $p$-divisible.